# Complex requirements for string split around select commas

Tags: ruby, regex, jruby

TL;DR

I need some help making a regex that will match any commas in a string that are side by side with unlimited white space around them and between them. The commas and their surrounding white space cannot be within matching single quotes or double quotes. I then need to capture the non-whitespace values from around those commas and count how many of those commas there are.

The values captured from around the commas will become their own values in the final array, while the commas that were counted will become nil values that are added to the final array.

Explanation of the problem:

This is a pretty complex problem so any help is greatly appreciated. I'm adding functionality to a library I've been using for a while now. I have this string that contains an array

```
"['d,og,f:asdf,:hello,",,\",,alsee',,,'ho,la', "-123,4,5.3", true,   :good, false,,, "gr\'\'\'true,\',\'ee\"n", ":::testme", true]"
```

I would like to split this string only around select commas so that I have an array containing the following values

```
'd,og,f:asdf,:hello,",,\",,alsee'
nil
nil
'ho,la'
"-123,4,5.3"
true
:good
false
nil
nil
"gr\'\'\'true,\',\'ee\"n"
":::testme"
true
```

Then `nil` values are coming from the side by side commas that are not contained in any string. I wrote the following regex to split the string above (I already got rid of the start and end brackets):

```
/(?<=(?:['\"]|false|true|^|,)),(?=(?:\s*(?:(?::[\w]+)|(?:(?::?(?:\"[\s\S]*\")|(?:'[\s\S]*'))|(?:false|true)))\s*(?:,|$)))/
```

This splits the string so I get these values:

```
(0) "'d,og,f:asdf,:hello,",,\",,alsee',,"
(1) "'ho,la'"
(2) " "-123,4,5.3""
(3) " true"
(4) "   :good, false,,"
(5) " "gr\'\'\'true,\',\'ee\"n""
(6) " ":::testme""
(7) " true"
```

All the values are strings as can be seen by their surrounding double quotes. They will not all end up that way though. A true or false will be converted to a boolean. The values surrounded by internal quotes will end up as strings. Then a value preceded with a `:` will end up as a symbol.

There are problems with the values at index `0` and `4`. Index `0` should be this:

```
(0.0) "'d,og,f:asdf,:hello,",,\",,alsee'"
(0.1) nil
(0.2) nil
```

As you can see, the two commas at the end are gone. They have become the two `nil` values you see above. Then the string starts at the first single quote and ends at the last single quote, signifying that this value in the array is a string.

Then index `4` (`"   :good, false,,"`) should be this:

```
(4.0) "   :good"
(4.1) " false"
(4.2) nil
(4.3) nil
```

The two commas at the end have become `nil`. Then `" false"` is it's own value which will later be converted to a boolean, while `"   :good"` is also it's own value and will later be converted to a symbol.

To fix the problem with index `4` I have all the values run through a second regex. Here it is:

```
/^(\s*:(?:(?:[\w]+|\"[\s\S]+\"|'[\s\S]+')\s*)),([\s\S]*)$/
```

Instead of splitting this one I get the capture groups. It ends up returning this array for the value at index `4`:

```
(4.0) "   :good"
(4.1) " false,,"
```

That's what I wanted except for one problem. The value at index `4.1` (`" false,,"`) has the two trailing commas which should be `nil` values in the array.

I need some help making a regex that will match any commas in a string that are side by side with unlimited white space around them and between them. The commas and their surrounding white space cannot be within matching single quotes or double quotes. I then need to capture the non-whitespace values from around those commas and count how many of those commas there are.

The values captured from around the commas will become their own values in the final array, while the commas that were counted will become nil values that are added to the final array.

Comment: Are you sure you want a regex and not a CSV parser?

Comment: Your input doesn't appear to be a string, as it contains unescaped double quotes.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I allow that in my _initial_ strings. I read the final values through an error checker that tells the user exactly what's wrong with any values. The unescaped double quotes problem you just mentioned would throw an error and tell the user exactly which value has the problem.

Comment: @user3277393 I'm going to take a look into csv. It might be exactly what I need.

Comment: Do you then escape the unescaped double quotes? If so, why haven't you done so in your example? If not, what are we to do with it? Here it is with the double quotes escaped: `"['d,og,f:asdf,:hello,\",,\",,alsee',,,'ho,la', \"-123,4,5.3\", true,   :good, false,,, \"gr\'\'\'true,\',\'ee\"n\", \":::testme\", true]"`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I leave it to the user to fix the problem. They are told that the string contains an unescaped double quote. Then they can decide what they'd like to do.

Comment: You said "I need some help making a regex that will match any commas in a string...", but you haven't given us a string to work with.  To apply a regex we need a string (i.e., an instance of the class `String`), not just a sequence of characters.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I don't think we're on the same page. Everything I've mentioned here has been in a string. Starting with `"['d,og,f:asdf,:hello,",,\",,alsee',,,'ho,la', "-123,4,5.3", true,   :good, false,,, "gr\'\'\'true,\',\'ee\"n", ":::testme", true]"`. Then it's been increasingly broken down into smaller strings by the regex I wrote above. The final regex I need will be used on all those substrings.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Also, I wrote my question specifically so that it would be language independent. It sounds like you're talking about a String in java. The language I'm doing this in is Ruby, but it doesn't really matter for this question. All I need is the correct regex with the right capture and non capture groups.

Comment: I was referring to Ruby (don't know Java). OK. (Downvote not mine.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out myself. You can see how it fits in with the rest if you look at the description of the question above.

```
/^(([\s]*,)*)[\s]*((?::[\w]+)|(?::?(?:\"[\s\S]*\")|(?:'[\s\S]*')|false|true))?(([\s]*,)*)$/
```

Answer (score 0):

"['d,og,f:asdf,:hello,"
,,\
",,alsee',,,'ho,la', "
-123,4,5.3
", true,   :good, false,,, "
gr\
'\'
I count 4 strings. 3 in double quotes and the last one in single quotes?
You say this is broken down into smaller strings by your regx. But what about the characters outside the 4 strings?
Sorry, it looks a bit of a mess.
Try putting it all in a here document string and then breaking it down by a regx.